# NLMIXR2: Error - Cannot figure out numeric time

Tags: r, bioinformatics, data-modeling, nlme

I am very interested on Model-Based Meta-Analysis and therefore, Non Linear Mixed Effect models.
I have been using the library "nlmixr2" on R but I have been struggling to identify what the error is in the model.

The code developed is:

```
library(nlmixr2)
library(xpose)
library(ggplot2)
library(xpose.nlmixr2)
library(rxode2)
library(symengine)


### Auxiliar function to aid on the synthetic data creation

Fevcreator<-function() {
  FEVw0 = c(rnorm(102,mean = 1.4,sd = 0.42),rnorm(105,mean = 1.4,sd = 0.44))
  FEVw14 = c((rnorm(102,mean = 0.073 ,sd = 0.0816 )-rnorm(102,mean = 0.066 ,sd = 0.0930 )),
             (rnorm(105,mean = -0.027 ,sd = 0.08 )-rnorm(105,mean = -0.041 ,sd = 0.0911 )))
  FEVw4 = FEVw0+FEVw14
  FEVw18 = c((rnorm(102,mean = 0.043 ,sd = 0.0728 )-rnorm(102,mean = 0.033 ,sd = 0.0847 )),
             (rnorm(105,mean = -0.055 ,sd = 0.0714 )-rnorm(105,mean = -0.074 ,sd = 0.0830 )))
  FEVw8 = FEVw0+FEVw18
  FEVw12 = c(rnorm(102,mean = 1.5,sd = 0.43),rnorm(105,mean = 1.6,sd = 0.45))
  FEVwx = rep(NA,207)
  FEV = c(FEVw0,FEVwx,FEVwx,FEVwx,FEVw4,FEVwx,FEVwx,FEVwx,FEVw8,FEVwx,FEVwx,FEVwx,FEVw12)
  FEV <- FEV*100
  return(FEV)
}


##If there is a Synthetic Patient data file in the working directory, load it,
##If not, create it.

if (file.exists("ModellingData.RData")) {
load("ModellingData.RData")
}else{
  
  ID<-1:207
  ID<-rep(ID,13)
  time<-c(rep("0.00",207),rep("1.00",207),rep("2.00",207),rep("3.00",207),rep("4.00",207),rep("5.00",207),
          rep("6.00",207),rep("7.00",207),rep("8.00",207),rep("9.00",207),rep("10.00",207),
          rep("11.00",207),rep("12.00",207))
  drug = c(rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105),
           rep("Roflumilast", 102), rep("Placebo", 105))
  dose=c(rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105),
         rep(3.5, 102), rep(0, 105))
  
  age<-c(rnorm(102, mean = 66.9, sd = 6.95), rnorm(105, mean = 66.9, sd = 7.71))
  age<-round(age)
  age<-c(age,age,age,age,age,age,age,age,age,age,age,age,age)
  body_mass<- c(rnorm(102, mean = 22.9, sd = 2.90), rnorm(105, mean = 22.4, sd = 2.68))
  body_mass<-c(body_mass,body_mass,body_mass,body_mass,body_mass,body_mass,
               body_mass,body_mass,body_mass,body_mass,body_mass,body_mass,body_mass)
  smoking_status <- c(rep("Current Smoker", 36), rep("Former Smoker", 66),
                      rep("Current Smoker", 38), rep("Former Smoker", 67))
  smoking_status<-rep(smoking_status,13)
  COPDsev <- c(rep("Very Severe", 4), rep("Severe", 44), rep("Moderate", 53), rep("Mild", 1),
               rep("Very Severe", 6), rep("Severe", 44), rep("Moderate", 53), rep("Mild", 2))
  COPDsev <- rep(COPDsev,13)
  DV<- Fevcreator()
  DV2<- Fevcreator()
  DV3<- Fevcreator()
  DV4<- Fevcreator()
  DV5<- Fevcreator()
  
  dataf <- data.frame(ID,time,drug,age,body_mass,smoking_status,COPDsev,dose,DV)
  dataf <- dataf[order(dataf$ID),]
  datatoaproximate<-data.frame(ID,time,DV,DV2,DV3,DV4,DV5)
  datatoaproximate <- datatoaproximate[order(datatoaproximate$ID),]
  
  pc<-pca(datatoaproximate,method = "bpca",nPcs = 5,center = TRUE)
  cObs<-completeObs(pc)
  cObs<-data.frame(cObs)
  cObs$mean <- rowMeans(cObs[,c('DV', 'DV2', 'DV3', 'DV4', 'DV5')], na.rm=TRUE)
  dataf$DV<-cObs$mean
  rm(ID,time,drug,age,body_mass,smoking_status,COPDsev,dose,datatoaproximate,pc,cObs,DV,DV2,DV3,DV4,DV5)
  save(dataf, file = "ModellingData.RData") 
}


###Model creation

jpkpdmodel <- function() {
  ini({
    tcl <- -log(0.8) # typical value of clearance
    tv <-  log(0.6)
    thl<- 0.03571429 ##Half life in weeks
    tEmax <- 104.9
    eta.cl + eta.v~c(1,0.1, 1)
    eta.bsln~10
    eta.hl~0.1
    add.err <- 0.1
  })
  model({
    cl <- exp(tcl-eta.cl)
    v <- exp(tv-eta.v)
    Ke<-cl/v
    hl <- exp(thl-eta.hl)
    Ka <- (0.69314718056)/hl
    baseline_FEV<-DV - exp(eta.bsln)

    Emax <- tEmax*0.1
    eff(0) <- baseline_FEV
    conc <- Central/v
    PD = Emax*conc
    d/dt(Central) =  Ka - cl / v * Central
    d/dt(eff) = Ka*PD -Ke*eff
    eff ~ add(add.err) 
  })
}

###Model execution

fit.s <- nlmixr2(jpkpdmodel, dataf,est="saem",control=list(print=0),table=list(cwres=TRUE, npde=TRUE))
```

When run, the execution reads:

```
ℹ parameter labels from comments will be replaced by 'label()'
→ loading into symengine environment...
→ pruning branches (`if`/`else`) of saem model...
✔ done
→ finding duplicate expressions in saem model...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 100%; 0:00:00 
→ optimizing duplicate expressions in saem model...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 100%; 0:00:00 
✔ done
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX14.0.sdk’
Calculating covariance matrix
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ loading into symengine environment...
→ pruning branches (`if`/`else`) of saem model...
✔ done
→ finding duplicate expressions in saem predOnly model 0...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ finding duplicate expressions in saem predOnly model 1...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ optimizing duplicate expressions in saem predOnly model 1...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ finding duplicate expressions in saem predOnly model 2...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ optimizing duplicate expressions in saem predOnly model 2...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

✔ done
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX14.0.sdk’

→ Calculating residuals/tables
→ loading into symengine environment...
→ pruning branches (`if`/`else`) of full model...
✔ done
→ calculate jacobian
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ calculate sensitivities
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ calculate ∂(f)/∂(η)
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ calculate ∂(R²)/∂(η)
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ finding duplicate expressions in inner model...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ optimizing duplicate expressions in inner model...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ finding duplicate expressions in EBE model...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ optimizing duplicate expressions in EBE model...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ compiling inner model...
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX14.0.sdk’

✔ done
→ finding duplicate expressions in FD model...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ optimizing duplicate expressions in FD model...
[====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====|====] 0:00:00 

→ compiling EBE model...
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX14.0.sdk’

✔ done
→ compiling events FD model...
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX14.0.sdk’

✔ done
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
exit of dop853 at x = 0.0000000000000000e+00, more than nmax = 70000 are needed
IDID=-2, larger nmax is needed
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX14.0.sdk’

Error : cannot figure out numeric time
Error: cannot figure out numeric time
```

I have tried changing the differential equations in the model, as well as changing the initial values.

The expectation is for the model to predict the effect of a bronchodilator on patients with COPD by measuring their FEV (Forced Expiratory Volume) at different stages in the trial.

Comment: I would recommend reworking this question to be more minimal. It is currently unclear whether the issue is with the particular model, or simply with getting any model to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it requires numeric time, here you have time as a character vector.

It was also answered on the (more active) github discussion group:

https://github.com/nlmixr2/nlmixr2/discussions/191